# How to check if a string is empty

Tags: if-statement, tcl, tk-toolkit

I need to check if a string (user input on an entry box) is empty or not and do some action based on that condition once I push the "Play" button.
This is my script:

```
entry .eInput -width 50 -relief sunken -justify center -textvariable Input
button .bAction  -text "Play" -width 30 -height 5 -activebackground green -font "-12" 

bind .bAction <1> {
 if {$Input ne ""}
  { puts "string is not empty"}
 else { puts "string is empty"}
                  }
```

But when I push the "Play" button this is the error:

```
wrong # args: no script following "$Input ne """ argument
wrong # args: no script following "$Input ne """ argument
    while executing
"if {$Input ne ""}"
    (command bound to event)
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you don't pass enough arguments to `if`

```
if {$Input ne ""}
```

Is not valid. In Tcl commands end with a newline.

Try to use

```
if {$Input ne ""} then {
    puts "string is not empty"
} else {
    puts "string is empty"
}
```

Comment: Some people prefer to use a backslash-newline in their `if`s and `while`s. I hate that, but some people insist.

Comment: Note that the `then` keyword argument is optional and usually omitted.

Comment: The `else` keyword is also optional, but often added for clarity.